# Why does space appearing between two views when I add scrollView, how can I get rid of that?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[space between two views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZZ3P.png)

I also tried `android:fillViewport="true"` but didn't work

Comment: what is the size of image?